# Preview assigned on all desktop on BigSur

Tags: display, pdf, preview, bug, big-sur

After updating from Big Sur from Catalina I have encountered some problems with the Preview app.

I use multiple Desktops (on the same screen) and after a pdf is opened, then when I switch to the another Desktop, Preview remains opened in the previous one.

I think it's a bug only for Preview because other apps stay in the Desktop in which they have been opened.

The only way to bypass this is to open pdfs with Safari or Acrobat.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click Preview in the Dock > Options.
Check it is not set to All Desktops. Default is 'None'.

[image]